# how does base class know about sub class method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

```
public class BaseClass {
    private String className;

    public BaseClass() {
        className = "[BaseClass]";
    }

    public void executeAB() {
        System.out.println(className + " executingAB()");
        executeA();
        executeB();
    }

    public void executeA() {
        System.out.println(this.className + " executingA()");
    }

    public void executeB() {
        System.out.println(this.className + " executingB()");
    }
}


public class SubClass extends BaseClass {

    private String className;

    public SubClass() {
        this.className = "[SubClass]";
    }

    public void executeA() {
        System.out.println(className + " executingA()");
    }

    public void executeC() {
        System.out.println(className + " executingC()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BaseClass t = new SubClass();
        t.executeAB();
        // t.executeC();
    }
}
```

In above case , Calling t.executeAB() results in output:

[BaseClass] executingAB()

[SubClass] executingA()

[BaseClass] executingB()

My Question is:

How does BaseClass know about excuteA() method from SubClass, while at the same time t.executeC() call is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975302/can-i-access-a-subclass-method-through-a-base-class-typed-reference) because BaseClass is not aware of executeC().

Comment: The answer is BaseClass *doesn't* know about how or if a method is overridden, and the magic of OOP is that it *doesn't have to know*. This is all handled behind the scenes by a method [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_dispatch) table.

Comment: This is one of the basic reason of having inheritance in OOPs word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of what you should be doing in inheritance. `extends` is a reserved word that was wisely chosen. The point of B extending A is to say that B is a subset of A with additional attributes. You're not supposed to redefine x in B; A should be handling x.  You should have not `className` declared in both classes.

As for your example:

```
 BaseClass t = new SubClass();
```

Calls the constructor for `SubClass`, which sets `className` of `SubClass` to `[SubClass]`.  The super contructor is also called, and `className` in `BaseClass` is set to `[BaseClass]`.

```
 t.executeAB();
```

Prints the className for `BaseClass` which is `[BaseClass]` and then calls:

```
 executeA(); 
 executeB();
```

`executeA()` is a called from `SubClass`, since t is a `SubClass` and it's defined, so we get `[SubClass]` and finally, `executeB()` is called from `BaseClass` so again, we get `[BaseClass]`.  As for why you can't call:

```
t.executeC()
```

Despite using the constructor for `SubClass`, `t` is a `BaseClass`.  According to the principles of OOP, it makes sense that you can't call `t.executeC()`, since it is not defined for `BaseClass`.

Comment: thanks steve. you mentioned "You're not supposed to redefine x in B", then what is use of overriding? do you mean i should have overriden executeAB() instead?

Comment: [Overriding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) is for redefining a method in a subclass. For example, overriding `toString()` makes sense because we want to be able to have a `String` representation of our objects (which may need to be different than our parent's `toString()`).  I'm not sure what your intentions were, but you're never going to be able to call `executeC()` on a `BaseClass` unless it's defined in `BaseClass` or one of its superclasses...Also, since you're new, you should check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your variable as `BaseClass t = new SubClass();` which means you allow space for a different subclass to instantiate. However, in order for this to be possible without breaking existing code, you can only use methods that are defined in the baseclass.